# How can i enable the button on checked the single checkbox in the Mat table?

Tags: angular, angular6, typescript2.0, angular-material-6, mat-table

I need to enable the submit button if checked the single check box from the "td" tag and its working fine when checked the master checkbox from "th" tag. Am using angular material. thanks in advance.

Find the Stackblitz link: https://angular-material2-5cgxqf.stackblitz.io/

**app.component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
            <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"></mat-checkbox>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"></mat-checkbox>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
/**Button*/

<button [disabled]="isButtonEnable">Submit</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

isButtonEnable:boolean =true;
/** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
      if(this.isAllSelected()){
              this.selection.clear();
              this.isButtonEnable = true;
          }else{
              this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
              this.isButtonEnable = false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Create the stackblitz demo

Comment: @SunilSingh Added example link

Comment: @Mathi please provide editor url of the stackblitz

Comment: @SunilSingh https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-5cgxqf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

You should check for any change in any checkbox. If any of the checkbox is selected then it should enable the submit button. Add the below snippet.

```
  constructor(){
    this.selection.changed.subscribe(item=>{
      this.isButtonEnable = this.selection.selected.length == 0;
    })
  }
```

Here is the working demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-p8r4pe

Comment: its working fine and also let me know about the below solution. whether its too correct or not.

Comment: That is the same solution.

Comment: It helps to enable/disable the Button based on the Checkbox selection. However, this solution causes screen getting freeze for some duration for large records (eg: for 1 lakh records selection together). It works fine for small records.

Answer (score 0):

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="SingleSelection(); $event.stopPropagation()"
                        (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                        [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
          </mat-checkbox>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
SingleSelection(){
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
      numSelected <= 0 ? this.isButtonEnable = false : this.isButtonEnable = true;
  }
```

this also working fine and please find the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-p8r4pe?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts